# invalid date format in javascript Date(2022,0,13) format

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

i am getting

```js
{
  "LeadCreatedDate": "Date(2022,0,13)" // <----- this type of date format
}
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J9MU.png)
is there any way i can format it in react any kind of help will be great. Thank you in advance.

[date format image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wSKYq.png)

Comment: Where does that object come from? If it comes from some API, it would make more sense to change the response to use the universally recognised [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format

Comment: getting this object from api which is parsing google sheet into json data.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the code you use to retrieve this object from the API

Comment: i added image please have a look

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help centre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you cannot do anything about the format of the API response, you'll have to manually parse it.

For example, you can use [*slice()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to extract the *arguments* part, [*split()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) them on comma characters to get an array, [*map()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) that to numbers and pass them to the `Date` constructor.

```js
// a function to transform your date values
const parseGSheetDate = (val) =>
  new Date(...val.slice(5, -1).split(",").map(Number));

// your original data
const data = {
  "LeadCreatedDate": "Date(2022,0,13)",
  "FullName": "Maryn Mccabe",
  "FirstName": "Maryn",
  "LastName": "Mccabe",
};

// replace the date fields with their parsed equivalents
const parsed = {
  ...data,
  LeadCreatedDate: parseGSheetDate(data.LeadCreatedDate),
};

console.log(parsed);
```

Comment: It's a lot less code to use `new Date(...val.match(/\d+/g))`. Or (heaven forbid) `eval('new ' + val)`. ;-)

Answer (score -2):

To do that, you need to format date before you push data. [There is](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring.asp) an information, how to do that properly

Comment: it is giving invalid date